# how do I create a servlet with parameters and a "/" at the ending?

Tags: java, servlets

My servlet needs to receive 2 parameters to respond.

My favorite solution (but it doesn't work in my context):

```
http://domain.com/?param1=something&param2=anything
```

because: I've another application which requires that a url ends with "/". But I can't create a servlet which accepts urls like "http://domain.com/?param1=something&param2=anything/" <<- / at the end.

My second solution is: 
http://domain.com/param1/param2/
I could split the requested url by "/" and I would have my 2 parameters. But it's not that nice..

Is there a better way to pass through 2 parameters and have an url which ends on a "/"?

Answer (score 1):

I think it is not possible. As it is defined in the HTTP RFC
    "http:" "//" host [ ":" port ] [ abs_path [ "?" query ]]
After the first "?" there is the query part. So in your example
    http://domain.com/?param1=something&param2=anything/
That means param2 value is anything/ (with the slash in the end)

Of course you can bind your servlet to /* url-pattern and process the parameters in the servlet using ServletRequest.getParameter(). But don't forget that your param2 will end with a /

Answer (score 1):

According to [RFC 3986, section 3.3](https://www.rfc-editor.org/rfc/rfc3986#section-3.3), it is possible to assign a set of parameters to each path segment like so:

```
http://domain.com/path;param1=value1;param2=value2/subpath/subsubpath/
```

So you can have parameters without the query part.

But the downside is:

- What you want to achieve is mabye not the intended use case for that feature.
- Other than for query parameters, there is no API support for segment parameters. So you have to parse the parameters on your own.